# Multiple class object render order

Tags: java, list, libgdx, render

I don't know how I can render multiple objects in order by their Y coordinate in libgdx.

I have 3 classes, one for each NPC. There is a Human class, an Orc class, and a Player class.

For recreating depth, I sorted my list of humans by Y from highest to lowest so that when they get rendered I can sort-of simulate depth. (This is a 2D game BTW). That worked fine using a Comparator.

I also used another comparator for my Orc list so that they can also be rendered in Y order.

However my problem is that when Humans and Orcs overlap they obviously break the depth due to the fact that the two lists are independently sorted.

Can combine both lists in some way and sort them as one to render all NPC types in order?

I can't figure it out as the comparator only allows you to use 1 class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a shared superclass or an interface that all your classes implement.
That superclass or interface needs to have a method to retrieve the Y coordinate.

You said that each of these classes is an NPC, so you could make a superclass called `NPC`:

```
public abstract class NPC {
     public abstract int getY();
}

public class Human extends NPC { /* ... has a getY() method */ }

public class Orc extends NPC { /* ... has a getY() method */ }
```

Then you can make a class that implements `Comparator<NPC>` that compares NPC's based on their `getY()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot Erwin! I did have a super class that all NPCs derive from. Have to do a whole lot of refactoring because of the way i formatted everything but your method works perfectly!

Comment: This is a good answer but I think in game entity designs, composition over inheritance should be favored.